# Static website builder "doorgets" showing error in installation

Tags: php, vs-web-site-project

i am new in PHP , I am trying to build an e-commerce. I made registration/login pages. Now i am thinking of using a static website builder softwere. I tried to user "doorgets" on my localhost. But its showing an error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZVRw.png)

how can i solve it ? and is that the best choice?

Comment: and what have you tried, what is the code?

Comment: but the error is self-explanatory... The file is not writeable, make it 777 or see if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self-explaining.

[image]

You have to make your `htdocs` folder writeable.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If answer is correct, please vote and accept the answer ;-) Thanks!

Comment: hay i will love to do that, i accept the answer but as i am new here system is not allowing me to vote :(